# Algebraic Value of A Covariant Derivative

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry

I am having trouble with the Notation for a question, and require some help. The question reads:

> If $(u_1, u_2)$ are coords on a surface $S$, show that:
>   $$\left<\left[\frac{D}{\partial u_1}, \frac{D}{\partial u_2}\right](V), V\right>=0$$

What does the first term in the Inner Product mean? I know that:
$$\left[\frac{DV}{\partial u_1}\right]$$
Stands for the Algebraic Value of the Covariant Derivative. But what does the above mean? The Algebraic Value of Both the Covariant Derivatives combined?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the algebraic value. But I would assume that it means the Lie Bracket of the two vector fields.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\left\langle #1\right\rangle}$The notation refers to the commutator of second covariant derivatives:
$$
\Brak{\left[\frac{D}{\dd u_{1}}, \frac{D}{\dd u_{2}}\right](V), V}
= \Brak{\left[\frac{D}{\dd u_{1}}\left(\frac{D}{\dd u_{2}}\right) - \frac{D}{\dd u_{2}}\left(\frac{D}{\dd u_{1}}\right)\right](V), V}.
$$
(The vanishing of this inner product is a fundamental symmetry of the Riemann curvature tensor.)

Comment: Based on the other questions the OP has asked with respect to this one, I don't think he or she knows Riemannian Geometry. Also, the problems the OP asked before this one had he or she explicitly compute $D/\partial u_i$ and so I think they need to use that i.e they are not supposed to adhere to this fundamental symmetry. I wrote this not because what you have is incorrect, just that I've seen the other questions the OP has been asking in reference to this one and I know this exercise is supposed to be a computational one.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Do you know how I'm supposed to continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing $ \langle u,w \rangle = u \cdot w$ and so you need to show that,

$$ \left(\begin{pmatrix} \nabla\omega_1 \cdot u_1 \\ \nabla\omega_2 \cdot u_1 \\ \nabla\omega_3 \cdot u_1 \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} \nabla\omega_1 \cdot u_2 \\ \nabla\omega_2 \cdot u_2 \\ \nabla\omega_3 \cdot u_2\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} \nabla\omega_1 \cdot u_2 \\ \nabla\omega_2 \cdot u_2 \\ \nabla\omega_3 \cdot u_2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \nabla\omega_1 \cdot u_1 \\ \nabla\omega_2 \cdot u_1 \\ \nabla\omega_3 \cdot u_1 \end{pmatrix}\right) \cdot V = 0  $$

where $V = \sum_j \left(V \cdot U_j\right) \ U_j$